# Python 2.x or 3.x on a Chromebook

Tags: python, chromebook

I'm trying to get into programming. I've worked to an extent in JavaScript, HTML, etc. I recently started Python, and I want to be able to use my Acer C720 Chromebook with Python. I've already installed a few things like the [Python Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/python-shell/diebclfbkfamdacginejnaookipodhng?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) from the Chrome Webstore, but these all lack certain modules that I need to use, such as tkinter. I was wandering if I could install a full version of Python (2.x or 3.x) via the terminal (I'm currently in dev mode).

Comment: You can use a Windows or Linux VM.

Comment: Otherwise, you'll need to kick your Chromebook into developer mode and dual boot Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[You will need to install crouton on your chromebook](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343), and then, after dual booting (with `sudo startxfce4`), you can open the terminal and proceed with your `TKinter` program.

Comment: Nice to see you around again.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi :) you too bro

Comment: I had actually installed Ubuntu with Gnome on my chromebook previously, but I didn't use it for anything... at all. I really kind of hoped that it would be possible to just install a port of Python directly to Chrome OS, since it is technically running a Linux kernel, but I think I may have to suffice with Ubuntu for now... Thanks, anyway!