# How can I use Tkinter on a Chromebook?

Tags: python, tkinter, chromebook

Is there any extensions, apps, or online applications that would allow me to use Tkinter on a Chromebook?

I'm trying to make a GUI for a program I've written and Tkinter seems nice, but I use Cloud9 which doesn't allow for graphics.

EDIT: I have an administrative lock on my Chromebook which makes me unable to install Ubuntu, which is why I need an online application, Chrome extension, or Chrome app.

Comment: Install Linux on the Chromebook. Then you'll have a proper OS with a window manager.

Comment: Similar question (not a dupe, IMO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551187/python-2-x-or-3-x-on-a-chromebook

Comment: @Martinelli Yes, I saw that question, but I decided I needed to ask my own because I can't install Ubuntu (see my new edit).

Answer (score 2):

You can use tkinter in Chromebook, just follow these steps:

1. Install Ubuntu in Chromebook, check this link [about How to Install Ubuntu on Chromebook.](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-install-linux-on-a-chromebook-and-unlock-its-ful-509039343)
2. After Installing Ubuntu, Now check if you have python or not. Open command terminal, type

   ```
   python
   ```
3. If you have not installed Python. Open command terminal and type

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3
   ```
4. Now for installing tkinter module type

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3-tk
   ```
5. Now check both python and tkinter from terminal by type

   ```html
   python3
   Python 3.5.1 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26)
   [GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>> from tkinter import *
   >>> root = Tk()
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it in my question, but I can't use Ubuntu on my Chromebook. (See the edit).

Comment: Then search in Chrome Web Store or Use any online Python shell

Comment: do you know of any online Python shells that allow for use of graphics like Tkinter?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` was just what I needed to get `turtle` working on my Chromebook.

Comment: I did this during Covid lockdown and everything worked perfectly except `.grid_remove()`