# Can I fake a `$DISPLAY` variable for tkinter on Cloud9?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, tkinter, cloud9

I primarily do my programming in Cloud 9, but I'm annoyed by the lack of graphics.

So, I've found out that I can save my [graphs as picture files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib-so-it-can-be), but when I try to even do that, I get an error from tkinter about not having a `$DISPLAY` variable (the same thing that led me to write [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579107/how-can-i-use-tkinter-on-a-chromebook) awhile ago).

Is there any way to make tkinter think I have this display variable so I can just get to saving the image without drawing anything?

(I'm not asking how to use graphics, I'm asking if it's possible to set a fake `$DISPLAY` variable that exists, but just doesn't work.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GUI's in Python on an online IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278867/using-guis-in-python-on-an-online-ide)

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34583288/5781248) shows how to select a matplotlib backend. Agg or SVG should be applicable and do not require tkinter.

Comment: I think I'm finding out a way to do it (By using matplotlib.use('Agg') as you mentioned @J.J.Hakala), but I'm still curious if there's a way to set a display variable without having it work. I'm not asking how to use graphics. I'm asking how to set a display variable that exists, but may be broken if a program tries to use it (or if doing so is even possible).